# bash script to get pull from local github

Tags: bash, git-bash

I wrote a bash script to get pulled automatically from master repository After it run that means auto enter the username and password. But it's not working. After executing fist command it again asked for a username.

my script is like this

```
#!/usr/bin/expect 
git pull origin master
expect "Username for 'http://192.168.2.xx:xxx':" 
send "myUsername\r"
expect "Password for 'http://192.168.2.xx:xxx':"
send "myPassword\r"
interact
```

Please help me out. Where I am mistaken

Comment: It looks like you've written an *Expect* script, not a Bash script.

Comment: Shall I do something like this by bash script

Comment: I think it might work with Expect, I don't know Expect at all and can't help you. However, the proper way to avoid having to enter user name and password in the first place is storing your public key in the Git service you're using and you won't be prompted any longer.

Comment: I try that too but its not work for me